# Move Mysql database from Windows Xampp to Linux MySql Server

Tags: mysql, windows

I 'am looking for a way to move some database in my local xampp to remote MySql Server , running into a Linux VM (Centos 7)

Any idea or any suggestions to do this migration?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is by using HeidiSQL, a free MySQL client. You can get it here:

https://www.heidisql.com/

You can configure the connection to the Windows XAMPP server and the Linux server, and then Heidi will be able to transfer the data directly from one server to the other. To do that:

- connect to the "source" server
- right-click on the database or table you want to transfer and select "Export Data As SQL"
- this will open a dialog box
- you likely will want to select the checkboxes to create the tables and databases you want to transfer if it's the 1st time you have transferred them
- if you want the data and not just the structure, be sure to select the data dropdown to transfer the data as well. I usually use "Delete + Insert", but your needs may vary
- in the output dropdown, select the "destination" server. In this case, it should be your Linux server
- In the Directory dropdown, you likely will want to leave it as [same as source server]
- Then click the Export button and wait